# How to get the text input in javafx using controller class?

Tags: java, javafx

I am new to javafx and building an java application using it with eclipse IDE. I learned how to create a main fx class and user interface with Scene builder. The main problem is i dont know how to get the user input (from the text field or from text area ) and display that text on console output or save that text into database after clicking 'save' button.

i want to know how can do above tasks using controller class in eclipse.

Any help would be appreciated and Thanks in advance.

Comment: with the getText() method !

Comment: ok but how can i attach it to button click?

Comment: I learnt it on YouTube programming knowledge channel. It is really very good tutorials to follow . Hope that helps since it is really very basic thing if you do with `scene builder`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advise you first to learn the JavaFX without (FXML/Controller) and for your question :

```
//Event when button clicked
yourButton.setOnAction(evt->{

    //display the text of your textField on the console
    System.out.println(yourTextField.getText());

});
```

As for the `Button` with a Controller, you have to separate your program into two parts (View **FXML** |Controller **java** ). The official documentation explains it very well [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/fxml_tutorial.htm), good luck !

Comment: It's ok :( @Bo Halim...ohk delete those comments I will ask u here itself

Comment: can we integrate a Google cloud account to a button using javaFx. I am working on a project where i want textfiles to be uploaded to my drive when i click button is it possible in java?  @Bo Halim